Does $A$ weakly compact in $\mathrm{C}(E,\mathbb{C})$, with $E$ compact, implies $A$ is compact?
Let $E$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and consider the Banach space $\mathrm{C}(E,\mathbb{C})$, of the continuous complex-valued functions, with the supremum norm.
Does $A$ weakly compact in $\mathrm{C}(E,\mathbb{C})$ imply $A$ is compact?
I know that in this Banach space weak convergence is equivalent with pointwise convergence, what would be useful is to have a subsequence which converges uniformly, but this I don't know if exists.

No. Let $E = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$. Then $A = \{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cup \{0\}$ is weakly compact (as it just consists of a sequence and its weak limit). But it’s not hard to check it is not norm-compact.
